# Facebook Login for Business - System User Access Token - It looks like this app isn't available

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, instagram-graph-api

I have a configuration set up for my app in Facebook which uses 'user access token' and this works fine, however, I need continuous access to my users' accounts so I switched to 'system-user access token' and now, whenever the login popup shows, I get the following error :

"It looks like this app isn't available"

The permissions are exactly the same and its the same app, just a different configuration. One uses 'user access token' and works fine and the other uses 'system-user access token' and doesn't work.

I've tried everything I can think of but for the life of me can't find the problem. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Were you every able to figure it out? I'm having the same issue and I've found a dozen similar questions as yours on here with no answers yet.

Comment: I believe this has something to do with being **Tech Provider**  [FB Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/facebook-login-for-business#access-tokens)

Answer (score 0):

In our case, it started working after setting `response_type=code` in the authorization URL.